# Running a batch file that's inside of a jar file

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, path

I'm attempting to call a batch file which is packaged inside of a jar file from the jar file itself. I'm not altogether sure this is possible, but I figured if anyone knew how it would be someone on here.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
public class FileLocationFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        String curdir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println("The User.dir = " + curdir);
        File newFile = new File (FileLocationFinder.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
        String strNewFile = newFile.toString();
        System.out.println("The New Path = " + strNewFile);     
        String abPath = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("The absolutePath = " + abPath);
        String conPath = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
        System.out.println("The Canonical Path = " + conPath);
        runDir(strNewFile);
    }
    public static void runDir(String dir){
        final int exitVal;
        final Process dirprocess;
        try {
            System.out.println("Running from curdir");
            dirprocess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(dir + "\\" + "SomeBatch.bat");
            try {
                exitVal = dirprocess.waitFor();
                if(exitVal == 0){
                    System.out.println("Dir worked");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The contents of SomeBatch.bat is

```
echo I was called
```

This runs as I expect it to when I compile then run. But when I create the jar file I get a lot of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell Java where to look for your .bat file, the way you have it now it's just searching the working directory for "dir\Somebat.bat". To search through the jar file for the .bat you need to utilize the ClassLoader's getResource or getResourceAsStream methods. You may then have to copy the .bat to the filesystem [such as the user.home directory] and use Runtime.exec() launch it from there.

Comment: Thank you, I would have loved some source to go with this, but just the same you helped me solve my problem. Your help is most appreciated.